# magento remove specific option from attribute for all products

Tags: magento, product

Excuse me for the difficulty I have had finding the answer for this; part of the problem is our product database is so large that trying to bootstrap load the products to *check* actually returns a stack error out of memory.

So I have many products that have a custom option (attribute) called (for example) "Waistband Size".  That normally has an option "Medium Small".  But, we no longer carry medium small.  So I want to remove that option from that attribute for all products.  How would I do this?

Answer (score 0):

Login to `admin panel > Catalog > Attributes > Manage Attributes` , Select your Attribute "`Waistband Size`", Then go to tab `Manage Label / Options` and delete the option which you want to delete.

Comment: I'm not completely clear on the `addAttributeToSelect` - I am specifically looking for custom attributes.  Also, how would I know the name of the custom attribute?  In adminhtml, you have the list and the first field is the name - would it be character the same, i.e. `Waistband Size`?